# Return nil when finding path for App Group

Tags: swift, xcode

I have enabled App Group and created a group called "group.com.classData"
[image]

And my code looks like this:

```
let plistPath3 = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.classData")
print(plistPath3) //returns "nil"
```

And it returns nil. Why does that happen?

Comment: Are you able to successfully create the above app group in Xcode? You have no red warning indicators below the App Groups dropdown?

Comment: @Fahim There's no error and there's no warining that's related to the problem.

Comment: At this point, I'm beginning to wonder if this is an Xcode glitch. Have you tried quitting Xcode and re-launching it? Also, after that, try deleting the shared group and re-creating it to see if it goes through smoothly?

Comment: @Fahim It works when I used a different version of Xcode (from build 8W109m to build 8E161). I guess it is just a Xcode glitch. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear that you were able to sort it out :)

Comment: I'm on Xcode 9.2, same issue.. App Group looks fine in xcode and developer portal. On both simulator and iPhone X the container URL is nil. I'm pulling my hair out trying to fix this. I've tried restarting Xcode, deleting and recreating the app group, changing the app group name... nothing works. Can anyone think of something else to try?

Comment: Had the same issue... just cleared the build. And then it's ok...

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this error while developing a share extension. It turned out that while I had added the App Group entitlement to the *app’s* target, I hadn’t added it to the *extension’s* target. I needed to select the extension from the project/target dropdown list:

[image: A screenshot of Xcode that shows the location of the dropdown list with the projects and targets.]

Then I clicked on the Capabilities tab and enabled App Groups. The App Group I had created for the application was already in the list; I just needed to check its checkbox. When I ran the app again, `containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:)` returned a non-nil value.

Comment: I am currently having the same issue. The app group is enabled in both of my targets and it's still returning nil. I have tripled check the `forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier ` string and it's the correct one. Any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: I did exactly the same.  Confusingly it was OK in the simulator, but only failed on an actual device.

Comment: For me, it doesn't work on extensions. Although I have everything set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

it take my 4 hour to solve it..
in my post pic

1. clips and clipsKeyBoard must both add
2. Capability must choose "All"  , first time i just chose Release... it's a sad story
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHYbP.png)